# Writing an algorithm which takes $O(\log n)$ to run

Tags: algorithms, sorting

there was a question in the exam as below:

> Let we have a sorted array consisting of $n$-many positive integers. Write a code that checks whether $k^{th}$ term is $k$ or not which takes $O(\log n)$ to run.

Even if I know that it will take much more time than  $O(\log n)$, I wrote a code in Magma CAS language. First, I said that the array we have is $A$ and created a new array $B$ such that $B[i]=A[i]-i$. Then for $i \in {1,\dots, n}$ I run the code to check whether $B[i]==0$ or not.

How can we write such a code with computing time $O(\log n)$? Thanks.

Comment: You can check in $O(1)$

Comment: At the moment you are not exploiting that the array is sorted. Also, you were supposed to check whether `A[i] == i`, why are you checking whether `B[i] == i`? That test should've been `B[i] == 0` to be correct. And @razvanelda, as I read it (especially with the attempted solution), you have to check that it holds for _all_ $k$. It's not clear though.

Comment: @Arthur Maybe you are right, OP is not very specific,

Comment: And I think you want to check if $B[i]==0$

Comment: Can an element repeat?

Comment: I think you want to check whether there exists k such that A[k]=k. If you know that A is strictly sorted, then your B is sorted (perhaps nonstrictly), so you can binary search it to find a value of zero. If A is nonstrictly sorted then you have serious problems.

Comment: Is $k$ an input to the problem, or is it quantified? If so, do you need it to hold for _all_ $k$ or just for _some_ $k$?

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to have the same number appear multiple times (necessarily consecutively) in the array, then it's impossible to do in $O(\log n)$ time.

Hint: I am assuming the same number cannot appear twice, and that what you want your algorithm to check is "is `A[k] == k` for all `k`?"

Then see what you can get out of the fact that the array is a *sorted* array containing *only positive numbers*, and think about how $O(\log n)$ algorithms usually work: By repeatedly splitting in half and discarding one part. Also, forget your `B` array, as simply creating it takes $O(n)$ time.

Comment: How do I do the split and discard job? I divide it up into 2 pieces, then search on the first one and not second?

Comment: @Ninja You look at the middle element, and depending on what that is, you either finish, or you discard the lower part and repeat the process on the higher part. In order to be able to look at a single element and conclude that all lower elements fulfill the property, though, it is essential that the array is sorted with unique, positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in $\mathcal{O}(1)$.
In C++ language:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// int A[size]
// Assume we already have the sorted array A
int main(){
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    if(A[k] == k){
        cout << "True" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "False" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But if you meant $\Theta(\log{n})$.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// int A[size]
// Assume we already have the sorted array A
int main(){
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    int idx1 = lower_bound(A,A+size,k)-A;
    int idx2 = upper_bound(A,A+size,k)-A;
    if(idx1 <= k && k < idx2){
        cout << "True" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "False" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The latter code uses binary search algorithm which takes averagely logarithmic time.